# jQuery variables turning out "undefined" even though made global

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, global-variables

I want to store a value from a JSON object in a global variable to use later in my code. Apparently this does not work even though it should make the `country` variable global.

```
$.getJSON(reverseGeoRequestURL, function(reverseGeoResult){
    window.country = reverseGeoResult.results[0].locations[0].adminArea1;
});
console.log(window.country);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getJSON` call is asynchronous. Put that `console.log` call inside the callback and it will not be undefined.

Comment: I see, but I need to get that value so I can use it later

Comment: You're going to have to continue processing the data only after getJSON has finished.